# Ubuntu 16.04 error with apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yum

Yesterday I updated Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, when I tried to install git, I got this error:

> The package linux-headers-4.4.0-65 needs to be reinstalled, but I
>   can't find an archive for it.

Then I tried to install another software, to the same error.

[image]

Comment: did you try `apt-get update` prior to `apt-get install git`?

Comment: I tried to change the source of ubuntu "and apt-get up update "before install these software, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Kali-Linux once. The thing that worked for me was:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I tried as you say,then some errors occur:dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.65.69); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 4.4.0.64.68.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.65.69); however: